# Exception while trying to log in using spring security version 5.4.6

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-security

I have a web application where I have been used.

```
org.springframework-version: 4.1.4.RELEASE
spring.security.version: 3.2.5.RELEASE
org.hibernate-version: 3.5.1-Final.
```

I'm trying to upgrade the spring, and the hibernate version where I successfully updated the following in my pom file

```
org.springframework-version: 5.3.6
spring.security.version: 5.4.6
org.hibernate-version: 5.4.31.Final
```

And I have also updated the related XML file where I mentioned the spring security beans. I'm using Postgres DB. I'm facing an issue. When I entered the username and password, and when I click on the submit button, it shows a 405 error page.

```
 20210514-14:26:43.504 sitepm-service [http-nio-8082-exec-9] WARN  org.hibernate.orm.deprecation.createCriteria - HHH90000022: Hibernate's legacy org.hibernate.Criteria API is deprecated; use the JPA javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery instead
20210514-14:27:03.386 sitepm-service [http-nio-8082-exec-10] WARN  o.s.w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver.logException - Resolved [org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException: Request method 'POST' not supported]
```

beans in my spring-security.xml file

```
<form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/"
            authentication-failure-url="/login?error" username-parameter="username"
            password-parameter="password" />
        <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" invalidate-session="false"  />
        
        <beans:bean id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
 class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
  <beans:property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
</beans:bean>

<beans:bean id="authenticationManager"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager">
     <!--<beans:property name="providers">  -->
  <beans:constructor-arg> 
    <beans:list>
      <beans:ref bean="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
    </beans:list>
  </beans:constructor-arg>
  <!-- </beans:property> -->
</beans:bean>


    <!-- Declare an authentication-manager to use a custom userDetailsService -->
    <authentication-manager>
        <authentication-provider user-service-ref="userDetailsService">
        <password-encoder hash="bcrypt" />
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

My userServiceImpl

```
@Service("userDetailsService")
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserDetailsService, UserService {
@Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String userName) throws UsernameNotFoundException, DataAccessException {

        String siteDomainName = (String) request.getServerName();
        logger.info("A user trying to login in domainnName " + siteDomainName+" with username/email "+userName);
        Site site = null;
        try {
            <!-- codes-->
        } catch (SiteManagerException e) {
            <!--error message-->
        }
        
    }
```

Login page HTML

```
<form id="loginForm" role="form" name='loginForm' action="${rc.getContextPath()}/j_spring_security_check" method='POST'>
            <div class="form-group">    
                <input id="login-username" type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Username or Email" autofocus>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input id="login-password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Password">
            </div>
            
            <#-- <div class="checkbox pad-btm text-left">
                <input class="magic-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="remember" name="_spring_security_remember_me" value="true">
                <label for="remember">Remember Me</label>
            </div> -->
            
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block" type="submit">Sign In</button>
        </form>
```

Can anyone help me to solve this?
Thanks

Comment: One issue that I see is that you are posting to `/j_spring_security_check`. Starting in Spring Security 4, this endpoint has changed to `/login`. Check out the migration guides from Spring Security [3 to 4](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/migrate/current/3-to-4/html5/migrate-3-to-4-xml.html) as a starting point.

Comment: @eleftheria-stein-kousathana Thanks for your response. I'm loading my login screen with the "/login" GET method. So I don't think I can point to this method on the login form submission.

Comment: Spring Security will still generate the POST "/login" endpoint even if you have a custom page at GET "/login".

Comment: @eleftheria-stein-kousathana If I change the controller method to POST '/login', how can I enter the login page? And I'm using the service class to authenticate the username and password. 'loadUserByUsername' is used to authenticate user credentials.